# Graphql + Relay graphql-relay-js dependency

Tags: graphql, relayjs

All the examples use graphql-relay-js on server
Can I handle graphql server without graphql-relay-js and use relay on client ?
Situation if one client use only graphql api and another client use relay to get data how to handle it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Relay requires that you follow certain conventions with your GraphQL schema; these conventions are documented in the [GraphQL Relay Specification](http://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/graphql-relay-specification.html#content). Note that these conventions are useful whether or not you're using Relay as the client.

`graphql-relay-js` is a set of helpers to make it easier to implement the above specification. This module is *not* required in order to use Relay - you're free to implement the above spec manually.